# how to Add custom Convention for caliburn.micro?

Tags: windows-phone-8, naming-conventions, caliburn.micro

In my project,I need to binding visibility of ui element to a bool property,as you know caliburn.micro has convention "CanName",so i think to add my own custom convention.
then i found this [Visibility Autobinding with naming convention i add this code in my project,but it not work and convention "CanName" doesn't work too.

```
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<FrameworkElement>(Control.VisibilityProperty, "Visibility", "IsVisible");
            var baseBindProperties = ViewModelBinder.BindProperties;
            ViewModelBinder.BindProperties = (frameWorkElements, viewModel) =>
            {
                BindVisiblityProperties(frameWorkElements, viewModel);
                return baseBindProperties(frameWorkElements, viewModel);
            };


static void BindVisiblityProperties(IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> items, Type viewModel)
        {
            foreach (FrameworkElement element in items)
            {
                string PropertyName = element.Name + "IsVisible";
                var property = viewModel.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(PropertyName);
                if (property != null)
                {
                    var convention = ConventionManager.GetElementConvention(typeof(FrameworkElement));
                    ConventionManager.SetBindingWithoutBindingOverwrite(viewModel, PropertyName, property,
                        element, convention, convention.GetBindableProperty(element));
                }
            }
        }
```

anyone know what wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using this Convention in my project without any issues. Here is a walkthrough:

In the `AppBootstrapper.cs` you include the Element Convention among other given Conventions

```cs
private static void AddCustomConventions()
{
    ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<FrameworkElement>(Control.VisibilityProperty, "Visibility", "IsVisible");
    var baseBindProperties = ViewModelBinder.BindProperties;
    ViewModelBinder.BindProperties = (frameWorkElements, viewModel) =>
    {
        BindVisiblityProperties(frameWorkElements, viewModel);
        return baseBindProperties(frameWorkElements, viewModel);
    };
}
```

and your helper method:

```cs
private static void BindVisiblityProperties(IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> items, Type viewModel)
{
    foreach (FrameworkElement element in items)
    {
        string PropertyName = element.Name + "IsVisible";
        var property = viewModel.GetPropertyCaseInsensitive(PropertyName);
        if (property != null)
        {
            var convention = ConventionManager.GetElementConvention(typeof(FrameworkElement));
            ConventionManager.SetBindingWithoutBindingOverwrite(
                viewModel, PropertyName, property, element, convention, convention.GetBindableProperty(element));
        }
    }
}
```

In your `PageView.xaml` you place your Controls and provide a `x:Name`

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button x:Name="StartRecord">start</Button>
    <Button x:Name="StopRecord">stop</Button>
    <Button x:Name="Foo">foo</Button>
    <Button x:Name="Bar">bar</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

within your `PageViewModel.cs` you place a `public property` of type `bool` with the suffix IsVisible

```cs
public bool FooIsVisible { get { return true; } }

public bool BarIsVisible { get { return false; } }
```

Comment: what about your useing environment? wp8 ?

Comment: I do not understand your follow-up question? can you put it in context of the given question / answer?

Comment: This seems to be not working with the current version. If I set a breakpoint in this method and open my page, the `frameWorkElements` contains only the top-level controls like `Grid` or `StackPanel`. Is there a recursive loop necessary?